# Variables scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, scope

I want result showed in console is `name2`, not `name1`

```
function showInfo() {
 var NAME="name1";//1
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
  response.name;   
  NAME="name2";//2
});
 FB.api("/me/picture?width=35&redirect=0&type=normal&height=35", function (response) {

   console.log(NAME);
 }
}
```

I did like obove but result in console is `name1`
How can i change NAME's value in //2 and the result in consle is `name2`. 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those calls are async, so you could try something like this:

```
function showInfo() {
    var NAME="name1";//1
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.name;   
        NAME="name2";//2
        FB.api("/me/picture?width=35&redirect=0&type=normal&height=35", function (response) {
            console.log(NAME);
        });
    });
}
```